# Uncaught TypeError: this.state.value.map is not a function when using React map

Tags: reactjs, state

My code is generating the following error: Uncaught TypeError: this.state.value.map is not a function. It seems to be retrieving the AJAX data fine, but won't iterate through the state using the JavaScript map function. Any ideas what's going wrong?

```
var LeaderBoardContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { value: [] }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var sortedByRecent = $.get('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent', function(data) {
    this.setState({ value: sortedByRecent })
    console.log(this.state)
    }.bind(this));
  },                                         

  render: function() {
    var rows = this.state.value.map(function(user){
      return (
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>{user.username}</td>
          <td>{user.recent}</td>
          <td>{user.alltime}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    })
    console.log(rows)
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
            <th>d</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {rows}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
});

React.render(<LeaderBoardContainer />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$.get` method the wrong way. It, itself, does not return value. You need to pass it a callback, which it will call and pass data, after AJAX request is completed. Like this:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    $.get('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent', function(data){
       this.setState({ value: data })
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[My code](https://jsfiddle.net/uyoh3gxm/)

I use setTimeout to simulate ajax.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    setTimeout(()=>
    this.setState({value: [{username: 'sam', recent: 1, alltime: 2}]}), 3000);
},
```

It seems no errors happened.
Maybe check the ajax api response.